# How to Set the value of a dropdown control in an excel template file using OPENXML

Tags: openxml

I have an excel template file. I need to fill the values of each cells of this excel template file. My excel file contain some drop down controls also. How I can set the dropdown selected value by using OPENXML.

Below is the code which I am using. It's working for other fields. But not working for dropdwon.

cell.CellValue = new CellValue("Company");

Comment: This has been answered here; For single value dropdown list in open xml
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553688/add-dropdown-validation-to-an-entire-excel-column-using-openxml For multiple selection dropdown list in open xml
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965492/how-to-create-cell-in-excel-file-having-multiple-selection-dropdown-using-openxm