# How to create cell in excel file having multiple selection dropdown using OpenXml?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, openxml

As I am working on functionality to write an excel file using **DocumentFormat.OpenXML** NuGet package.

I can create the dropdown list on a specific cell in excel but my requirement is, that specific cell should be allowed the user to select **multiple items** from dropdown list.

Using the below code I am able to create dropdown on cell but that cell is not allowing the multiple selections.

```
            DataValidation dataValidation = new DataValidation
            {
                Type = DataValidationValues.List,
                AllowBlank = true,
                SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "B1" },
                Formula1 = new Formula1("'Cricket Team'!$A$1:$A$3")

            };

            DataValidations dataValidations = worksheet1.GetFirstChild<DataValidations>();
            if (dataValidations != null)
            {
                dataValidations.Count = dataValidations.Count + 1;
                dataValidations.Append(dataValidation);
            }
            else
            {
                DataValidations newdataValidations = new DataValidations();
                newdataValidations.Append(dataValidation);
                newdataValidations.Count = 1;
                worksheet1.Append(newdataValidations);
            }
```

Sample Output of this code is:

[image]

My requirement is, **the user can select multiple items from dropdown list**.

Comment: did u find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

> my requirement is, that specific cell should be allowed the user to select multiple items from dropdown list.

You can try to set and apply the filter to the range via **AutoFilter**, like below.

```
Worksheet sheet1 = new Worksheet();
sheet1.Append(sheetData);

// set the AutoFilter
// and set the range based on your requirement and data items
AutoFilter autoFilterForName = new AutoFilter(){ Reference = "B1:B" + 3 }; 

sheet1.Append(autoFilterForName);
```

Test Result

[image]